# Rules for Obtaining Dual Circuits with Diodes

Tags: ltspice, thevenin, norton

After several hours of trial and error, the shown circuits are dual of each other, in the Thevenin Norton sense.

Note how similar their responses are. And why it included an additional resistor, intrigued me.

I am having some problem finding a concept or a rule on how circuit with diodes can be dualized each other so that a circuit with a voltage variable output can be reflected with a current variable output.

Is there some underlying concept on how transform them in some more procedural way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use an ideal diode?  If so, the default diode named `D` is not ideal.  If you want to use an ideal diode model you need to define one using LTspice's piecewise-linear diode model.  See the section titled "D. Diode" in the built-in LTspice help for info and an example of a `.model` statement for one.  https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm

Comment: If you want to create a dual circuit, you have to dualise **everything**. I'm not sure what the dual of a diode is at the moment, but I do know it's not a diode!

Answer (score 3):

The diodes act as switches, and for simple intro textbook level duals you need two dual circuits that are switched: one works when one diode conducts, the other when the other conducts.

Since you've left the diodes in, they still act as switches, and they alternate between the two dual configurations, but it's not exactly a dual as you've noticed. The diodes don't belong - you'd need behavioral dual equivalents of diodes. That way you could follow a procedural approach, and you'd get exact duality without manual tweaking of values.